# DDMS for DalvikVM launched via command line

Tags: android, dalvik, ddms

I have a normal Java application I am running on DalvikVM after converting the byte code into dex code. I manually invoke the DalvikVM from the adb shell to execute it. To enable debugging, I explictly pass arguments to DalvikVM: "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_android_adb,suspend=n,server=y"

Using DDMS I can attach put breakpoints and trace code but DDMS's memory allocation tracker doesn't work. I tried Googling and the only relevant thing I could find was this:

> Because command-line applications don't include the client-side DDM
>   setup, features like thread monitoring and allocation tracking will
>   not be available in DDMS.

[Source: Basic Dalvik VM Invocation](http://www.milk.com/kodebase/dalvik-docs-mirror/docs/hello-world.html)

So how do I include the client-side DDM setup? Is there any special code I need to add in order to make the application DDM aware or pass extra params to Dalvik?